# eclipse crash after opening on ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, root

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb5855ae7, pid=1431, tid=3028896624
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b20
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.9.2
# Distribution: Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS, package 6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# J  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.VersionFormatParser$Qualifier.parse([Lorg/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/metadata/VersionFormatParser$Fragment;ILjava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/metadata/VersionFormat$TreeInfo;)Z
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/skowron-line/Pobrane/eclipse/hs_err_pid1431.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
#
Aborted
```

Above screen shows error after I have tryied to lunch eclipse as root, as simple user it works just fine.  In error log file there is some things but I dont understand them.

Does someone had such problem ? And know the anwser

Comment: What's in /home/skowron-line/Pobrane/eclipse/hs_err_pid1431.log?

Answer (score 1):

That's a JVM crash, maybe *initiated* by some eclipse related class. Update to the latest and greatest Java an verify if it is reproduceable.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin` after this it shows that there is nothing to install

Comment: @skowron-line - hmm, ok, openjdk has different numbers then oracle jdk. u26 is the most recent over there..

Answer (score 0):

You have *installed* Sun/Oracle's JDK but it looks like you are still *running* OpenJDK. Try calling java -version to make sure, and then call:

update-java-alternatives

to set Oracle's Java as the default.

Comment: `root@skowron-line:/home/skowron-line/Pobrane/eclipse# sudo update-java-alternatives -a
update-alternatives: error: there is no alternative for mozilla-javaplugin.so.` this is what i got - but it works now :) strange

Comment: I think that's right. You should now be using Sun's JVM by default (rather than OpenJDK). The error regarding the plugin is "normal" and doesn't affect the other parts of the Java distribution.